Difficulty to scrape HTML page from a dynamic generated website with Python
I'm trying to retrieve some data from a website with python. The website seems to generate its content with Javascript so I cannot use the standard requests library. I tried the module requests-html and Selenium that both handle javascript content, but the problem is that I still cannot get the html page of this website.

https://www.lvmh.com/en/join-us/our-job-offers?PRD-en-us-timestamp-desc%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bmaison%5D%5B0%5D=Kendo

I'm expecting to get the exact same view as what I have when I'm inspecting the page with my browser. For instant, I can clearly see all the information about the open positions. But when I fetch the page source with requests-html or Selenium, I get a page without any information of the open position.
For instance, if I want to retrieve the name of the open position, it is located in the span with the class "ais-Highlight-nonHighlighted". I can see it in my browser, but I am not able to get this data with python.
HTML page when inspecting through my browser, showing the data to retrieve (the job position name)
What I want is to get the html of the webpage, just like requests, and then process is with BeautifulSoup.
I tried with requests-html :
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url = "https://www.lvmh.com/en/join-us/our-job-offers?PRD-en-us-timestamp-desc%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bmaison%5D%5B0%5D=Kendo"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(wait=5)

print(r.html.html)
print(r.html.text)
print(r.text)
job_name = r.html.find('.ais-Highlight-nonHighlighted')

session.close()

--> print does not display the job position name and job_name is empty
I tried with Selenium :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
url = "https://www.lvmh.com/en/join-us/our-job-offers?PRD-en-us-timestamp-desc%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bmaison%5D%5B0%5D=Kendo"

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)

data_source = driver.page_source
data_execute = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

driver.quit()

--> data_source and data_execute both does not include the job position name
None worked... if anyone can help me on that it will be grateful.

You're approach using selenium is not optimum. Don't try to get the page source but rather use selenium's built-in functionality for navigation.
For example:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

def text(e):
    if r := e.text:
        return r
    return e.get_attribute("textContent")

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")

url = "https://www.lvmh.com/en/join-us/our-job-offers?PRD-en-us-timestamp-desc%5BrefinementList%5D%5Bmaison%5D%5B0%5D=Kendo"

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.ais-Highlight-nonHighlighted"
    for span in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(selector)):
        print(text(span))

Output (partial):
...

COPY OF DIRECTOR, VISUAL DESIGN
KENDO
San Francisco
United States
Permanent Job
Minimum 10 years
Full Time
PACKAGING CREATIVE DIRECTOR
KENDO
San Francisco
United States
Permanent Job
Minimum 10 years
Full Time


Thank you, it is working. I was expecting to get the html code (just like a standard request) and then process it with BeautifulSoup, but it's also good like this.

The content you see on the page is loaded from external URL via Javascript. You can simulate this request to get data, e.g.:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    "queries": [
        {
            "indexName": "PRD-en-us-timestamp-desc",
            "params": {
                "facetFilters": [["maison:Kendo"]],
                "facets": [
                    "businessGroupFilter",
                    "cityFilter",
                    "contractFilter",
                    "countryRegionFilter",
                    "fullTimePartTimeFilter",
                    "functionFilter",
                    "geographicAreaFilter",
                    "maison",
                    "regionStateFilter",
                    "requiredExperienceFilter",
                    "workModeFilter",
                ],
                "filters": "category:job",
                "highlightPostTag": " ",
                "highlightPreTag": " ",
                "hitsPerPage": 10,
                "maxValuesPerFacet": 10,
                "query": "",
                "tagFilters": "",
            },
        },
        {
            "indexName": "PRD-en-us-timestamp-desc",
            "params": {
                "analytics": False,
                "clickAnalytics": False,
                "facets": "maison",
                "filters": "category:job",
                "highlightPostTag": " ",
                "highlightPreTag": " ",
                "hitsPerPage": 0,
                "maxValuesPerFacet": 10,
                "page": 0,
                "query": "",
            },
        },
    ]
}

api_url = "https://www.lvmh.com/api/search"

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

for h in data["results"][0]["hits"]:
    name = h["name"]
    desc = BeautifulSoup(h["description"], "html.parser")
    print(name)
    print(desc.text)
    print("-" * 80)

Prints:

...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------              
Executive Assistant                                                                           
ABOUT KENDO                                                                                   
Kendo Holdings, Inc. is a San Francisco-based beauty brand developer and wholesaler. A play on the words “can do”, Kendo has become the hub of creativity and next generation beauty product development for global Sephora channels and selective retailers outside of Sephora.
Kendo is owned by LVMH Moët Hennessy - Louis Vuitton, the world’s largest luxury group. The Kendo house of brands presently includes: Marc Jacobs Beauty, Kat Von D, Ole Henriksen, Bite and Fenty. Through original development, collaborations and acquisitions, the Kendo stable of brands will always be creative, inspiring and innovative. A dynamic engine of speed, expertise an
d market-savvy, the Kendo team continues to redefine the beauty industry through great product, great storytelling, and great retail and direct-to-consumer partnerships.                   
EXECUTIVE ASSISTANT POSITION SUMMARY                                                          
The ideal individual will have the ability to exercise good judgment in a variety of situations, with strong written and verbal communication, administrative, and organizational skills, and the ability to maintain a realistic balance among multiple priorities. The Executive Assistant will have the ability to work independently on projects, from conception to completion, and
 must be able to work under pressure at times to handle a wide variety of activities and confidential matters with discretion.                                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------              
Copy of Director, Visual Design                                                               
Overview:                                                                                     
The Global Visual + Experiential Designer Director for Kendo will lead the creative vision for all IRL spaces across the globe and for all brands at Kendo bringing together design, merchandising, and copy to formulate a north star creative vision for how our brands are presented. This critical creative leadership role will translate strategy, campaigns and 2d assets into 3d
 storytelling for the consumer in a compelling way. This Director would be very experienced in concepting and drafting blue sky thinking for retail & experiential initiatives with the strong ability to marry those ideas with the consumer, our brand DNA, innovative retail concepts and the business needs to deliver best-in-class experiences that meet the business objectives. 
This role will be the first to identify the changing retail & consumer landscape and propose ideas on how to stay ahead. This role would support all Kendo brands and offer a wide range of projects across retail spaces, merchandising, marketing, store design, experiential marketing for the consumer, influencers, founders and retail partners.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------              

...


Thank you, it works ! As I understand, I need to adapt the research criteria to get what I need (I'm not familiar with json).

In addition: you can also use re.sub(r"<[^>]*>", "", h[“description”]) to get the text from the description faster.
